# Tooltip title on image using mouseover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to display an element title on the image(tooltip size). I  found out the current element title

```
$('.downloadPdf').mouseover(function(){
    var currentelement = $(this).attr('title');
});
```

downloadPdf is common class on elements.

Actually I have a menu bar in bottom in which I have some icons. These icons are functional. 
Here I want whenever a user hovers over these icons, their title must come over the image. This image is nothing, just a tooltip shape.

But how to append it on image? And its position must be on the element only. so how do I get the position also. So confused and spend at least 3 hours on this small task. Any help would be appreciated. I am so bad when it comes to use css effectively.

Comment: If it's hover,only, I suggest CSS only, don't need JS on this task.

Comment: A title on an image will automatically show up as a tooltip!

Comment: Wait, if you have already a `title=""`, doing this will get you 2 tooltips?

Comment: I have to create tooltip actually on hover.

Comment: The tooltip that I want must be with given tooltip image.

Comment: Use the alt attribute of the <img /> tag

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jub3t7ru/ please hover on the sentence, is that what you want?

Comment: @Robin I don't know about that one, but it is definitely not W3's recommendation on making the browser render engine.

Comment: No its coming by default DanielCheung I want in the format that I designed as an image. That is why I want to add this image to tooltip.

Comment: @NituDhaka so are you asking to make a tooltip that displays an image?

Comment: it's getting a bit confusing. when the mouse hovers over an image do you want to display image name or something else?

Comment: "*I want to display an element title on the image*" - the actual `title` tooltip, or a styled element? "*(tooltip size)*" - what does that mean, exactly? "*downloadPdf is common class on elements. but how to append it to on image*" - you want to add a class to an `<img>` element? Take some time, edit and improve your question so that it can be understood. I realise you may not speak English fluently, but if you could ask a friend to review your question, it would be a good idea to do so.

Comment: @NituDhaka Can you give an example in "When the element is (text/image/has class xxx), I want it to display (text:xxx/image/xxx)"?

Comment: Oh I think I didn't explain it properly. give me 5 mins let me edit  once the question with proper example.

Comment: @DavidThomas Your advice is a great one, I hate people just vote down questions and not explain. Your tip should be displayed when someone makes a question. Sadly, Meta is not too great of a platform, just saying. :)

Comment: nitu do you know jquery?

Comment: yes @Robin littlebit.

Comment: @NituDhaka Do you have any image result .

Comment: then visit this link it http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/demos/

Comment: it is a very good plugin for tooltips

Comment: Robin I am downloading it.

Comment: hi @NituDhaka now you can used to this http://jsfiddle.net/jyvpfd4p/  and how to create this http://rohitazadmalik.blogspot.in/2014/03/how-to-create-tooltips-with-jquery.html

Comment: i suggest you wait for other people to answer and if their answer is better you implement that if not then use this plugin.because adding a plugin will increase the load time of your page by little bit.

Comment: @NituDhaka: Is this what you are looking for:  http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/cs822gg7/1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok. The easiest and simpliest way is to add `title` attribute to your image. Hovering this image will cause the native browser tooltip to show over the image.

Check this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p88nm7wa/) (place your mouse cursor over the image of pdf-icon).

Also these questions has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11716916/tooltip-on-image).

Comment: yes it occurs by default rit? so can we change the design of default tooltip?

Comment: Simple answer: no. But there is a way to make your own tooltip and show it instead of native one. But this demands changes in your html. I will make an example in 10 mins.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an organized demo I made in the last few minutes: http://jsfiddle.net/47g8dnLx/1/

#### <sub>HTML:</sub>

```
<div class="icon">
    <img src="path/to/image">
    <span>Text</span>
</div>
```

`.icon` is the wrapper of each icon. `span` is the tool tip text.

The demo is just a **working demo**. No mean of code tidiness or efficient!

Please note that I omitted the `title=""` because it's not needed for custom tool tips.

Comment: +1 Good one Daniel. In fact you could use the `title` as well if required. http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/47g8dnLx/2/

Comment: @abhitalks Well... :/ Adding title in there just adds more code and the span's content renders useless. _If possible_, putting the title in the `<img>` would be a better alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Hi i think you want to this modify title

now used to this code

```js
$.fn.autoSuggest = function(){   return this.each(function(index, elm){ 
if(!$(elm).is('[data-title]')){ 
$(elm).attr('data-title', $(elm).attr('title')).attr('title', ''); 
}; 

$(elm).on('mouseenter', function(){ 
var element = $(this), 
posTop = element.offset().top + element.outerHeight() + 10, 
posLeft = element.offset().left, 
toolTipWidth = element.outerWidth() > 90 ? element.outerWidth() : 250, 
titleText = element.attr('data-title'); 
if(titleText && titleText != ''){ 
$('<div />', {class: 'autoSugest', text : titleText, css : {left: posLeft, top: posTop, maxWidth: toolTipWidth}}).appendTo('body').fadeIn(); 
}else{ 
return false; 
} 
}); 
$(elm).on('mouseout', function(){ 
$('.autoSugest').fadeOut(function(){ 
$(this).remove(); 
}); 
}); 
}); }; 
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('.title').autoSuggest(); });
```

```css
.downloadPdf {
    width:64px;
    height:64px
}

.autoSugest{background:#fffdef;border:1px solid #cac6ad; 
-webkit-border-radius:4px; 
-moz-border-radius:4px; 
border-radius:4px;color:#7f7943; 
display:none; 
font-size:12px; 
padding:7px 15px; 
position:absolute; 
min-width:100px; 
-o-box-sizing:border-box; 
-ms-box-sizing:border-box; 
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box; 
-moz-box-sizing:border-box; 
box-sizing:border-box;}

.autoSugest:after{ 
content:"";
 border-left: solid 10px transparent;
border-right: solid 10px transparent;
border-bottom: solid 10px #cac6ad;
position: absolute;
top: -11px;
left: 12px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="downloadPdf title" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/graphicloads/filetype/256/pdf-icon.png" title="Text for tooltip">
```

**[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jyvpfd4p/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

I just found it (not done by me).

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('img').hover(function() {
     // Hover over code
     var title = $(this).attr('alt');
     $(this).data('tipText', title);
     $('<p class="tooltip"></p>').text(title).appendTo('body').fadeIn('slow');
   }, function() {
     // Hover out code
     $(this).attr('alt', $(this).data('tipText'));
     $('.tooltip').remove();
   });
 });
```

```css
            .tooltip {
                display: none;
                position: absolute;
                border: 1px solid #333;
                background-color: #161616;
                border-radius: 5px;
                padding: 10px;
                color: #fff;
                font-size: 12px Arial;
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://www.google.com.br/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" alt="Google Logo" />
```