# How to add tooltip to image on hover with CSS

Tags: css, hover, tooltip

I have three images, on hover they increase in size using :hover in css. When a user hovers over the image I'd also like a tooltip to appear with a description of the image (I should also be able to position the tooltip).

**HTML**

```
<div class="bottle-container">
<div class="click-to-top"><img src="image-1.png" alt="Image 1" />Tooltip text</div>
<div class="click-to-top" style="z-index:5;"><img src="image-2.png" alt="Image 2" /></div>
<div class="click-to-top last"><img src="image-3.png" alt="Image 3" /></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
container{
max-width:600px;
margin:0 auto;
min-height:450px;
}

div.click-to-top {
display:inline-block;
position:relative;
max-width:160px;
}

div.click-to-top:hover{
z-index:10;
}

div.click-to-top img{
-webkit-transition: all 0.8s;
moz-transition: all 0.8s;
transition: all 0.8s;
width:130px;
}

div.click-to-top img:hover{
width:140px;
z-index:10;
}
```

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11716916/tooltip-on-image) has to be the best because it uses built-in html attributes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can wrap the text into a `<span></span>` and show it on parent `:hover`

> CSS

```
div.click-to-top span {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
}

div.click-to-top:hover span {
  display: block;
}
```

> HTML

```
<div class="click-to-top">
  <img src="http://lorempicsum.com/futurama/350/200/1" alt="Image 1" />
  <span>Tooltip text</span>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w0wtkgpu/3/)

Answer (score 3):

Look at this codepen http://codepen.io/mlegg10/pen/reqGMZ

```css
/* `border-box`... ALL THE THINGS! */
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  margin: 64px auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 100%;
  max-width: 640px;
  width: 94%;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

header,
.tooltip,
.tooltip p {
  margin: 4em 0;
  text-align: center;
}

/**
 * Tooltip Styles
 */

/* Add this attribute to the element that needs a tooltip */
[data-tooltip] {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Hide the tooltip content by default */
[data-tooltip]:before,
[data-tooltip]:after {
  visibility: hidden;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

/* Position tooltip above the element */
[data-tooltip]:before {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 150%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-left: -80px;
  padding: 7px;
  width: 160px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #000;
  background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 20%, 0.9);
  color: #fff;
  content: attr(data-tooltip);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

/* Triangle hack to make tooltip look like a speech bubble */
[data-tooltip]:after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 150%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5px solid #000;
  border-top: 5px solid hsla(0, 0%, 20%, 0.9);
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
}

/* Show tooltip content on hover */
[data-tooltip]:hover:before,
[data-tooltip]:hover:after {
  visibility: visible;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="tooltip">
    <p><button data-tooltip="I’m the tooltip text.">I’m a button with a tooltip</button></p>
</div>
```