# CSS-only image tooltip

Tags: html, css, image, tooltip

I try to create a CSS-only IMG-Tooltip generated from an attribute value.
I tried the following code

```
<img src="blabla.jpg" data-caption="this is my caption" />
```

and the CSS-Code:

```
img {
  position: relative;
}
img:after {
  content: attr(data-caption);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2em;
  left: 2em;
  z-index: 2
}
```

Such a way is no problem with div containers. But how can I get this working on images?

Thank you,
Thomas

Comment: Images cannot have pseudo-elements.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7396469/why-dont-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-work-with-img-elements

Answer (score 0):

Well you have multiple ways to create a tooltip using CSS but here is a small example to create tooltip for image.

In below example I have use `title` attribute of `html` which also works kind of similar.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/42/Shaqi_jrvej.jpg/1200px-Shaqi_jrvej.jpg" title="imgae">



  
</body>
</html>
```

You'll find more useful answer here : [Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921421/how-to-add-tooltip-to-image-on-hover-with-css)

**Let me know if you find this code helpful**.

Comment: I am looking for a way to realize it without any further html markup. As mentioned before it works with other elements like divs. IMG-Tags does not seem to recognize :after pseudo elements. 
-> The markup is used in a cms and we can't control the output markup.