# Bootstrap Tooltips

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, tooltip, popper.js

I currently have an img tag that when people hover over it, I want a tooltip to appear. As I understand it, you can only place a tooltip in an 'a' tag, is it possible to surround/encapsulate my img tag in order to do so or does this not work?

e.g.

```
<li class="list-inline-item">
    <a href="whatever" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="auto top" title="Arduino">
        <img src="https://png.icons8.com/color/50/000000/arduino.png">
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Please! check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11716916/tooltip-on-image

Comment: that's for a normal tooltip, i'm trying to get a bootstrap tooltip to work but thanks for the link.

Answer (score 2):

Well this works.

```
<span class="d-inline-block" tabindex="0" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Disabled tooltip">
   <img src="https://png.icons8.com/color/50/000000/arduino.png">
</span>
```

A tooltip doesn't have to be in an 'a' tag.

Dont forget to add:

```
<script>    
$(function () {
      $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
    })
</script>
```

See the bootstrap [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/tooltips/)

Comment: great, can i add the function into a js file with a jQuery doc onload already? or should i place it at the bottom of my html doc?

Comment: Yes, you should include it in a file with jquery doc onload, as long as you inlcude this script in your html :)

Comment: i'm getting this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
    at lt (popper.js:629)
    at Object.onLoad (popper.js:1134)
    at popper.js:2342
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at new t (popper.js:2340)
    at s.T.show (tooltip.js:287)
    at s.T._enter (tooltip.js:548)
    at HTMLSpanElement.<anonymous> (tooltip.js:480)
    at HTMLSpanElement.handle (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLSpanElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:2)