# How to add a tooltip to an image in html?

Tags: html, css, tooltip

I have an image and I want to add a tooltip.
this is the code:

```
<img src='info.svg' width='20' height='20' />
```

how do I add a tooltip?

Comment: maybe this might be useful https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_tooltip.asp

Comment: We expect you try smething before asking, SO is not a free  coding service. please read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tooltip on image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11716916/tooltip-on-image)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `title` attribute for any html tags:

`<img src='info.svg' width='20' height='20' title='Hello'/>`

Answer (score 0):

While SergeiMinaev's answer is absolutely great and it is evidently true that you can have a tooltip with the `title` attribute, I will focus on customizable alternatives. We can wrap a `div` around the image and a hidden div with `absolute` position that will only be displayed on `hover`.

```css
.hoverable-image {
    position: absolute;
}

.hoverable-image > div {
    position: absolute;
    left: 40%;
    top: 40%;
}

.hoverable-image:not(:hover) > div {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="hoverable-image">
    <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-illustration/3d-small-people-jumped-pleasure-260nw-67359301.jpg">
    <div><span style="background-color: gray; color: purple;">Some Tooltip</span></div>
</div>
```